# Duplicate question with good answer to a different question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

So while searching for how to rename a database in MySQL *Workbench*, I came across the duplicate-flagged "[How do I rename a MySQL schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545634/how-do-i-rename-a-mysql-schema)", which has just one answer -- and [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4545726/27358), as it happens, is the answer to my Workbench question.

It turns out the author of the answer misunderstood the OP, and what the OP was really asking was how to rename the database *in MySQL* -- a question which does, in fact, already have [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490515/how-does-one-rename-a-schema-in-mysql) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name).

Would it be appropriate to edit the question to match the (useful) answer, since otherwise the question will probably eventually be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Agreed the answer does not match the question, and the answer is somewhat of a good answer, being that it was asked in '10 and the user probably wouldn't care anymore I would agree with editing the question, and would offer a reopen vote if the question was changed enough to no longer be a duplicate. However, this may not be the opinion of The Many

Comment: Seems like this is the converse of the more common situation in which a question is edited so it *no longer* matches existing answers. Either way, the basic point remains: if there's a good answer, or more than one, that assume the question should be more or less X, then the question should indeed probably be made to be more or less X... at least if there's no answers that contrarily assume the question is Y.

Comment: Look at the tags: mysql-workbench is in there and judging from the edit history it was not added after the fact. That question is not misunderstood, it is misleading.

Comment: Would we not say you should open a new question and close it as a duplicate of the old question that has your answer?

Answer (score 6):

I supposed you are concerned with preserving this useful information for posterity. Instead of editing the question, you could create a new question "Rename a schema in MySQL Workbench" that is appropriate to the answer you want to preserve. And then copy/paste the answer from the old question to the new one (giving credit to the original author).